# PrimeReact theme doesn't apply correctly to PrimeReact components

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, primereact

I'm trying to make a Menubar PrimeReact component for my React app, and I'm trying to apply one of the PrimeReact themes by importing it and it makes the page look weird.

I'm trying import "./../../node_modules/primereact/resources/themes/nano/theme.css"; and it looks like there's no CSS at all except for a background color change. However, when I do import "./../../node_modules/primereact/resources/primereact.css", it looks fine.

Here's the code I have:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { PrimeReactProvider, PrimeReactContext } from 'primereact/api'
import { Menubar } from 'primereact/menubar';
import { InputText } from 'primereact/inputtext';
import "./../../node_modules/primereact/resources/themes/nano/theme.css";

export default function TabSidebar()
{
    const items = [
        {
            label: 'File',
            icon: 'pi pi-fw pi-file',
            items: [
                {
                    label: 'New',
                    icon: 'pi pi-fw pi-plus',
                    items: [
                        {
                            label: 'Bookmark',
                            icon: 'pi pi-fw pi-bookmark'
                        },
                        {
                            label: 'Video',
                            icon: 'pi pi-fw pi-video'
                        },

                    ]
                },
                {
                    label: 'Delete',
                    icon: 'pi pi-fw pi-trash'
                },
                {
                    separator: true
                },
                {
                    label: 'Export',
                    icon: 'pi pi-fw pi-external-link'
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            label: 'Edit',
            icon: 'pi pi-fw pi-pencil',
            items: [
                {
                    label: 'Left',
                    icon: 'pi pi-fw pi-align-left'
                },
                {
                    label: 'Right',
                    icon: 'pi pi-fw pi-align-right'
                },
                {
                    label: 'Center',
                    icon: 'pi pi-fw pi-align-center'
                },
                {
                    label: 'Justify',
                    icon: 'pi pi-fw pi-align-justify'
                },

            ]
        },
        {
            label: 'Users',
            icon: 'pi pi-fw pi-user',
            items: [
                {
                    label: 'New',
                    icon: 'pi pi-fw pi-user-plus',

                },
                {
                    label: 'Delete',
                    icon: 'pi pi-fw pi-user-minus',

                },
                {
                    label: 'Search',
                    icon: 'pi pi-fw pi-users',
                    items: [
                        {
                            label: 'Filter',
                            icon: 'pi pi-fw pi-filter',
                            items: [
                                {
                                    label: 'Print',
                                    icon: 'pi pi-fw pi-print'
                                }
                            ]
                        },
                        {
                            icon: 'pi pi-fw pi-bars',
                            label: 'List'
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            label: 'Events',
            icon: 'pi pi-fw pi-calendar',
            items: [
                {
                    label: 'Edit',
                    icon: 'pi pi-fw pi-pencil',
                    items: [
                        {
                            label: 'Save',
                            icon: 'pi pi-fw pi-calendar-plus'
                        },
                        {
                            label: 'Delete',
                            icon: 'pi pi-fw pi-calendar-minus'
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    label: 'Archive',
                    icon: 'pi pi-fw pi-calendar-times',
                    items: [
                        {
                            label: 'Remove',
                            icon: 'pi pi-fw pi-calendar-minus'
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            label: 'Quit',
            icon: 'pi pi-fw pi-power-off'
        }
    ];

    const start = <img alt="logo" src="https://primefaces.org/cdn/primereact/images/logo.png" height="40" className="mr-2"></img>;
    const end = <InputText placeholder="Search" type="text" className="w-full" />;

    return (
        <PrimeReactProvider>
<Menubar model={items} start={start} end={end} />

        </PrimeReactProvider>
    )
}
```

Anyone know how to fix?

I tried applying a theme to a PrimeReact and I expected it to display the component with the desired theme. Instead, it incorrectly laid out the component.

Answer (score 0):

You are not importing all the CSS correctly like this.

```js
import 'primereact/resources/themes/lara-light-indigo/theme.css';// theme
import 'primereact/resources/primereact.css'; // core css
```

The primereact.css is required as is the CORE CSS to accompany the theme.